# I have been trying to publish a page using Github Pages and I am having trouble with deployment

Tags: web, github, deployment

I am have been trying to use Github pages to publish a website I developed and I am having trouble setting it up.

The source for that website is: https://github.com/Tanav1/AWorldWithoutH8

[image: source]

Its publication settings are:

[image: publication]

And the result is visible at: https://tanav1.github.io/AWorldWithoutH8/

Comment: It seems published